# openpyxl: how to refer a cell in another sheet inside a combination of formula using OFFSET and INDIRECT functions

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formula, openpyxl

I am trying to automate quiz grading for trainees. The steps we follow are as follows:

1. pull quiz data from ODKaggregate server as a CSV file and save it in xlsx format
2. Load the data in python (I am using Pycharm IDE)
3. Create a new sheet for every question in the quiz
4. Automate calculating the average scores of every question inside the xlsx form

I am successful in addressing steps 1-3. In order to automate the calculation of average score in every sheet, I am using the AVERAGE, OFFSET and INDIRECT excel functions. However, I can not refer to a cell coordinate in another sheet inside the INDIRECT function, it is returning `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` . Here are the lines of code I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
quiz_excel=pd.read_csv (r'path_to_csv_file.csv')
quiz_excel.to_excel (r'path_to_xlsx_file.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
wb: Workbook = load_workbook (r'path_to_xlsx_file.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
max_row = wb.active.max_row - 1 # the '-1' is to ignore the column heading'

for i in range(max_row+1):
    wb.create_sheet('Q')

wb['Q1']['B2'] = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!AC1",1,0,1,3))" # i am getting the error from this line of code.
```

can anyone help me with the problem, please. your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Please include the complete traceback.

Comment: You are trying to put “ inside a “-quoted string, which gives a syntax error - you need to escape the internal “ like \” and also I think you’re missing a closing ) at the end - i.e. "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(\"'Sheet1'!AC1\",1,0,1,3)))"

Comment: Actually you might not need those internal \” at all, try it without.

Comment: Thanks a lot @balmy, escaping the internal " with \" solve the problem. I was supposed to  edit the code to make work as: `"=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(\"'Sheet1'!\"& \"AC1\"),1,0,1,3))`.

Comment: I have a follow up question: I want to pass a string variable which contains the cell coordinate into the function, but on the output excel I am getting `#REF!` error. the example would go like this: `"=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(\"'Sheet1'!\"& \"cell_coordinate\"),1,0,1,3))"`.  The "cell _coordinate" being a string with a value `AC1`.

Comment: Use an f-string like `f”=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(\”’Sheet1’!{cell_coordinate}\”),1,0,1,3)”` - make your code print this string and you can check it looks good.

Comment: Thank a lot! after a few code formatting, it worked like a charm!! it gave the chance to learn the formatted string feature of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @balmy, escaping the internal " with " solve the problem. I was supposed to edit the code to make work as: "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"& "AC1"),1,0,1,3))